# Multibit LWE Encryption

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, lwe

What's the simplest way to encrypt multiple bits with LWE public key cryptosystem?  Some paper say use a different secret key for each bit of the message.  Does that mean the length of the message need to be agreed upon before transmission?

Comment: Could you post the link of some papers?

Comment: Do you only want to do public-key operations, or do you care about FHE as well? The first case is rather simple, but the second may benefit from techniques like you're describing.